# How can I easily display an array of codes from MongoDB in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, mean-stack

I'm trying to build a simple application that allows users to submit codes to a database and simply display those codes back to them. My database model looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaWZ1.png), where the text is the actual code to be displayed. For some reason I cannot get the codes to display on the webpage and it's probably something small. Currently, nothing displays on the webpage, but the API test works in soapUI

Here is my API to get codes

```
router.get("/codes", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    Code.find({}, function(err, codes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(501).send({
          message: `MongoDB Exception: ${err}`,
        });
      } else {
        console.log(codes);
        res.json(codes);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Server Exception: ${e.message}`,
    });
  }
});
```

my code schema

```
let codeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    text: { type: String, unique: true, dropDups: true },
  },

  { collection: "codes" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Code", codeSchema);
```

My home.ts file

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  codes = new MatTableDataSource<Code>([]);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchCodes(): void {
    this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/codes')
      .subscribe((res: Code[]) => {
        this.codes.data = res;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchCodes();
    console.log(this.codes);
  }
}
```

and my HTML

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="code">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Codes </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code"> {{codes}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Is this your full HTML file or you just skipped the table tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your ts file should also define the displayed columns like this:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['code'];
```

And your HTML file should be like this:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="codes" class="mat-elevation-z8">
         
     <ng-container matColumnDef="code">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Code</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code"> {{code}} </td>
     </ng-container>
            
            
     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>
```

The above should work only if your API returns an array of strings e.x.

```
const codes = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3'];
```

Comment: thanks! i got something to display now, however it's displaying as [object Object]

Comment: @johnf what is your Code object structure?

Comment: I have these 2 lines in the TS file:   codes = new MatTableDataSource<Code>([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['code']; and the text field in the code schema, I wonder if I need to somehow access that in the database as well

Comment: @johnf Try to check what's the result of the call with `console.log(res)`. Could you provide one of the containted objects?

Comment: yes! i got this from the console.log [link](https://i.imgur.com/h2GPK3w_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand)

Comment: Is text proerty what you want to show? Try chaning `{{ code }}` to `{{ code.text }}`

Comment: yes it is, and when i do that it shows nothing instead of object Object. weird

Comment: Try this `{{ code[0].text }}`

Comment: hmm that gives an error in the console:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text'). i wonder if i have to define/declare text somewhere

Comment: No I dont think so. One last try `{{ code[0]?.text }}`
If this is still not working try experimenting a little bit with the result you are getting. Try to console.log and find the path to the text for each code.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code"> {{codes | json}} </td>
```